# Recursively get data from a query result in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, recursion

SQL gurus

I have a table structure as follows

```
Id        Name        IdPartner
Id1       name1           
Id2       Name2       Id1
Id3       name3       Id1
Id4       name4       Id2
Id5       name5       Id3
```

I need to write a query that would recursively loop through the table to find the partners.

I.e Given an Id say Id1 here, I need to pull out all the Names where Id1 is listed as a partner, So my query need to pull up Name3 and Name2. Subsequently in the same query I also need to pull the names where Name3 and Name2 are also listed as partners. So in this case if I give the input to the SP as Id1 I should effectively get a list that read as below

```
   Id          Name
  Id2         name2
  Id3         name3
  Id4         name4
  Id5         name5
```

I havent worked with recursively getting the data in SQL. Someone told me I could use a common table expression, but I fail to see how that would help me. I have been breaking my head over this for over a day and all I can come up with is the idea of using a cursor.

Any help in this regard helps

Comment: I do not know exact scenario , What do you mean by recursively? can you explain it a little more? You will need to write a program that hit the database recursively.

Comment: it could be multiple, meaning to say Id1 could be partnered with Id3,Id4 and Id2 could also be partnered with Id3 and id4.

Comment: I am not understanding you completely. But I think your need a very simple Select query. Select * from table where IdPartner=Id1

Comment: What I mean to say is when the query first pulls up records where id1 is a partner, it then need to recursively look in the result set to see if any Ids in the resultset are partners with other records. Here for example when I first pull up Id2 and Id3 when I pass Id1 to the SP, the SP has to now recursively loom into the table where Id2 is a partner and Id3 is a partner and subsequently look into that resultset as well till there are no more partners.

Comment: now i got it. let me think a little more.

Comment: The very first trick which comes in my mind is , you first select the record against id1 in a temp table , then write another query like this Select * from table where idpartner in (Select id from temptable) and in the end apply union operator on the temp table and the second query.

Comment: Agreed but that will give me data only up to the second level. if I have a third level where say id6 has a Idpartner of Id5 in the above example this might not work.

Comment: hmmm , now I really need to implement this first. But a solution could be , store your second level results in the temp table too. and then select the record from table for newly added IDs. repeat it until second select statements returns 0. and in the end select temp table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following returns the related, but not requested, rows:

```
declare @Gurus as Table ( Id VarChar(4), Name VarChar(16), IdPartner VarChar(4) )
insert into @Gurus ( Id, Name, IdPartner ) values
  ( 'Id1', 'name1', NULL ),
  ( 'Id2', 'Name2', 'Id1' ),
  ( 'Id3', 'Name3', 'Id1' ),
  ( 'Id4', 'Name4', 'Id2' ),
  ( 'Id5', 'Name5', 'Id3' )

declare @TargetId as VarChar(4) = 'Id1'

; with RelatedGurus as (
  -- Anchor: Get the rows that are partners of the target row.
  select Id, Name, IdPartner
    from @Gurus
    where IdPartner = @TargetId
  union all
  -- Recursion: Add any rows that are partners to the rows just added.
  select G.Id, G.Name, G.IdPartner
    from @Gurus as G inner join
      RelatedGurus as RG on RG.Id = G.IdPartner )
  -- Display the result.
  select Id, Name
    from RelatedGurus
    order by Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmptesttable') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #tmptesttable

    DECLARE @ParentID NVARCHAR(50)
    SET @ParentID = 'Id1'

    SELECT 
        *
    INTO
        #tmptesttable
    FROM 

    (
        SELECT 'Id1','name1', NULL UNION ALL          
        SELECT 'Id2','Name2', 'Id1' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Id3','name3', 'Id1' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Id4','name4', 'Id2' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Id5','name5', 'Id3'
    ) testData (Id,Name,IdPartner)

    ;WITH cteHierarchy AS (
        SELECT Id,Name,IdPartner FROM #tmptesttable WHERE Id = @ParentID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            tmptesttable.Id,tmptesttable.Name,tmptesttable.IdPartner 
        FROM 
            #tmptesttable  tmptesttable
        INNER JOIN
            cteHierarchy
        ON
            cteHierarchy.Id = tmptesttable.IdPartner
    )
    SELECT * FROM cteHierarchy WHERE IdPartner IS NOT NULL
```